# Which speed setting of a mixer-grinder should be used for which purpose?

Tags: equipment

Slow, fast, medium are the speed settings in those appliances, for example [this mixer-grinder](http://www.amazon.in/Morphy-Richards-Icon-Classique-750-Watt/dp/B008P7IJEE?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=e39d63cf-618c-42f7-82e7-339604db5ded).

Why are there 3 settings, why not only fast? Which setting should be used in which case?

Comment: When you say "grinder," do you mean a meat grinder, a coffee grinder, or something else?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I am talking about this: http://www.amazon.in/Morphy-Richards-Icon-Classique-750-Watt/dp/B008P7IJEE?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=e39d63cf-618c-42f7-82e7-339604db5ded @Athanasius

Comment: Ah, I see - I thought you were talking about three different appliances originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for mixer.

At the low speed you have stir / mix.  At the high speed you have whip.

You would stir eggs to make scrambled eggs.  And you would whip cream to make whipped cream.